# Is there a way to run PHP long loop code faster?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a code that runs a query on an external (slow) API and loops through a lot of variables and inserts data, sends email, ect'. 
This is the main function as an example:

```
// MAIN: Cron Job Function
public function kas_alert() {


    // 0. Deletes all the saved data from the `data` table 1 month+ ago. 
    // $this->kas_model->clean_old_rows();

    // 1. Get 'prod' table
    $data['table'] = $this->kas_model->prod_table();


    // 2. Go through each row -
    foreach ( $data['table'] as $row ) {

        // 2.2. Gets all vars from the first query.
        $last_row_query = $this->kas_model->get_last_row_of_tag($row->tag_id);
        $last_row       = $last_row_query[0];
        $l_aaa_id       = $last_row->prod_aaa_id;
        $l_and_id       = $last_row->prod_bbb_id;
        $l_r_aaa        = $last_row->dat_data1_aaa;
        $l_r_and        = $last_row->dat_data1_bbb;
        $l_t_aaa        = $last_row->dat_data2_aaa;
        $l_t_and        = $last_row->dat_data2_bbb;
        $tagword        = $last_row->tag_word;
        $tag_id         = $last_row->tag_id;
        $country        = $last_row->kay_country;
        $email          = $last_row->u_email;
        $prod_name      = $last_row->prod_name;
        // For the Weekly report:
        $prod_id        = $last_row->prod_id;
        $today          = date('Y-m-d');

        // 2.3. Run the tagword query again for today on each one of the tags and insert to DB. 
        if ( ($l_aaa_id != 0) || ( !empty($l_aaa_id) ) ) {
            $aaa_data_today   = $this->get_data1_aaa_by_id_and_kw($l_aaa_id, $tagword, $country);
        } else{
            $aaa_data_today['data1']       = 0;
            $aaa_data_today['data2']      = 0;
            $aaa_data_today['data3'] = 0;
        }

        if ( ($l_and_id != 0) || ( !empty($l_and_id) ) ) {
            $bbb_data_today = $this->get_data1_bbb_by_id_and_kw($l_and_id, $tagword, $country);
        } else {
            $bbb_data_today['data1']      = 0;
            $bbb_data_today['data2']    = 0;
            $bbb_data_today['data3'] = 0;
        } 

        // 2.4. Insert the new variables to the "data" table. 
        if ($this->kas_model->insert_new_tag_to_db( $tag_id, $aaa_data_today['data1'], $bbb_data_today['data1'], $aaa_data_today['data2'], $bbb_data_today['data2'], $aaa_data_today['data3'], $bbb_data_today['data3']) ){
        }


        // Kas Alert Outputs ($SEND is echoed in it's original function)
        echo "<h1>prod Name: $prod_id</h1>";
        echo "<h2>tag id: $tag_id</h2>";
        var_dump($aaa_data_today);
        echo "aaa old: ";
        echo $l_r_aaa;
        echo "<br> aaa new: ";
        echo $aaa_data_today['data1']; 

        var_dump($bbb_data_today);
        echo "<br> bbb old: ";
        echo $l_r_and;
        echo "<br> bbb new: ";
        echo $bbb_data_today['data1'];

        // 2.5. Check if there is a need to send something
        $send = $this->check_if_send($l_aaa_id, $l_and_id, $l_r_aaa, $aaa_data_today['data1'], $l_r_and, $bbb_data_today['data1']);

        // 2.6. If there is a trigger, send the email!
        if ($send) {
            $this->send_mail($l_aaa_id, $l_and_id, $aaa_data_today['data1'], $bbb_data_today['data1'], $l_r_aaa, $l_r_and, $tagword, $email, $prod_name);
        }

    }


}
```

This CodeIgniter controller is runs every day and I get this running (Cronjob) for too long using almost nothing from the CPU and RAM (RAM is at 400M/4.25G and CPU at ONLY 0.7%-1.3%).

I wonder if there's an option to split all foreach loops to smaller threads (and I'm not sure if forking will do here) and run all the foreach loops in parallel but in a way that it wont get my server crashing.

I'm no DevOps and really interested learning - What should I do in this case?

Comment: How many e-mails typically get set? If every e-mail involves contacting a server that could be a time-consumer right there.

Comment: @BenHillier so that that controller does is getting data from the DB and running each row on a really slow external API and looking for resemblance, and if there is non, it runs the same query with the variable "index=2" ect... and when the variable is found it gets the data and inserts to the DB, goes through 10 if statements that decide if old and new data has to be sent to the admin, and if yes, it sends and email (smtp). 
emails might cause the program run slow, but there might be an other reason which is the slow API, and I'm trying to find a way to split all foreach to run separately

Comment: I would rather use a Queue Server and would have the loop push tasks in the Queue Server and then let the Workers handle the tasks independently.
This would not necesarely run faster, but it would definitely not use let resources, would not cause a timeout and would not block the execution of the application.